# Change encoding of HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, encoding, servlets, character-encoding

I have an API that returns XML, it actually returns it using the default encoding (I believe it's UTF-8), but now requirements have changed and we need to return everything in UTF-16LE.

My question is: is there an easy way of doing this? I have access to the response just before the calls complete so I was wondering if I could do something like

```
//This method does not exist
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-16LE");
```

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:
The method mentioned is the one to use. I was using an old version (2.3) of the servlet API that did not include it. Changing the version fixed it all.**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Uhh, the method *does* exist, [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29)

> Sets the character encoding (MIME
>   charset) of the response being sent to
>   the client, for example, to UTF-8. If
>   the character encoding has already
>   been set by
>   setContentType(java.lang.String) or
>   setLocale(java.util.Locale), this
>   method overrides it. Calling
>   setContentType(java.lang.String) with
>   the String  of text/html and calling
>   this method with the String of UTF-8 
>   is equivalent with calling
>   setContentType with the String of
>   text/html; charset=UTF-8.

Comment: ..which is introduced in Servlet API 2.4. Although this is over 5 years old and nowadays everyone ought already have at least that version, you need to ensure that you're using it as well.

Comment: It might be worth noting here that the default encoding is ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 15):

As others have stated, use either:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-16LE");
```

or:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-16LE");
```

...but make sure you do this *before* calling response.getWriter();   ...!

Comment: Thanks, Tim, calling it after `response.getWriter()` is what caused us issues!

Comment: The comment about calling it before `response.getWriter()` should be an answer in and of itself.

Answer (score 9):

First

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-16LE");
```

Then, make sure you're actually emitting that encoding!

Answer (score 1):

I found that you MUST set the character encoding to at least UTF-8 because the default is ISO-8859-1. The ISO-8859-1 character set doesn't account for some extended characters. I wrote a helper function to use what is sent in the "Accept" header:

```
public static void setResponseCharacterSet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    String type = "UTF-8";
    if(request.getHeader("accept") != null)
    {
        String[] params = request.getHeader("accept").split("charset=");
        if(params.length == 2) {
            type = params[1];
        }
    }
    response.setCharacterEncoding(type);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

just do the following thing:

```
byte[] k =xml.getBytes("UTF-16"); // xml is the string with unicode content.  getBytes("UTF-16") encodes given String into a sequence of bytes and returns an array of bytes. you can use xml.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET); for utf-8 encoding

response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setContentLength(k.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(k);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```