# How to generate Chinese characters from a Java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, character, cjk

My servlet looks like this

```
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
  {
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    out.println("<Html><Head><Title>Signup</Title></Head>\n<Body>\n");
    out.println("\u5982 电话\n");
    out.println("</Body>\n</Html>");
  }
```

My browser can display Chinese characters from other websites.
I'm trying 2 different ways to display Chinese characters, but they all showed up as ???
What's the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Have you verified that your browser+system+font combination will display any Chinese at all, by outputing html escaped versions of the unicode?  e.g. "&#x5982;"?   http://unicodinator.com

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849058/change-encoding-of-httpservletresponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No explicit encoding has been set for the response. The response would therefore be written by the container with the default encoding of ISO-8859-1.

You'll therefore need to specify the appropriate character encoding using the [HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) or [HttpServletResponse.setContentType](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) methods. This would be either of:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("GB18030");
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=GB18030");
```

You may also use UTF-8 as the explicit encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to send Unicode, have your servlet send UTF-8, and have the browser locale set up properly to interpret the characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the character encoding as UTF-8 worked for me.

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```